# Find full file name from part of it

Tags: php

I have a directory that include debian packages and looks like that:

[image]

inside Depiction folder i have a Description for each package, each folder contains an index.php file

Inside that description page, i'm trying to find a way to get the full filename of the deb by only having the first part of the file `com.name.app1` and it will automatically get the second part.

The reason i'm trying to do this, its because i will have to update the debian packages later and i don't want to edit the description page every time i update a package

And the filename i'm using it for some counter/filesize and other scripts

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `glob` and regex with `preg_match` you can find the files:

```
<?php

     // define which app
    $app = "app1";

    // Search the directory for possible matches
        foreach (glob("/com.name.".$app."*") as $filename) {
            $filename . "\n";

            preg_match('/\\d\\.\\d-\\d_.*\\.deb/', $filename, $matches);
            echo "filename: com.name.".$app."_{$matches[0]}\n";
        }
?>
```

Result:

> com.name.app1_1.0-1_iphoneos-arm.deb

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your reply but it didn't work, i just don't get any output its blank

Comment: You need to change the directory `/com.name` to where your files are located. For example: `/var/www/website.com/cydia/debs/com.name`

Comment: @Chta7, One more quick thing to note; you can remove the line `$filename . "\n";` I only had it there for testing. Cheers!

Comment: Hey there, sorry to bother you but i'm having a little issue, when i have a verion of a package 1.1 like `com.name.app1_1.1_iphoneos-arm.deb` i am getting this result `com.name.app1_` is there anyway to get it work with versions `x.x-x` and `x.x` ? Thanks.

Comment: After reading about `preg_match` i managed to fix it by replacing `-\\d` with `.*` so it would be like that `preg_match('/\\d\\.\\d.*_.*\\.deb/', $filename, $matches);`